# Spark Docker configuration

Tags: java, apache-spark, docker, docker-compose

I'm using https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/docker-compose.yml to start a docker compose to run a Spark environment. It seems to successfully start - I can connect to http://master:8080 and it says that the spark master is spark://master:7077. 'master' is mapped to the Docker container IP in `Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`.

I have a Java app.

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
            .master("spark://master:7077")
            .getOrCreate();
```

What I get is the following error:

> 19:20:18.240 [netty-rpc-connection-0] DEBUG
>   o.a.s.n.c.TransportClientFactory - Connection to
>   master/192.168.99.100:7077 successful, running bootstraps...
>   19:20:18.240 [netty-rpc-connection-0] INFO 
>   o.a.s.n.c.TransportClientFactory - Successfully created connection to
>   master/192.168.99.100:7077 after 18 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
>   19:20:18.244 [netty-rpc-connection-0] DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler -
>   -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 32768 19:20:18.244 [netty-rpc-connection-0] DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler -
>   -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2 19:20:18.244 [netty-rpc-connection-0] DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler -
>   -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16 19:20:18.244 [netty-rpc-connection-0] DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler -
>   -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8 19:20:18.265 [appclient-register-master-threadpool-0] WARN 
>   o.a.s.d.c.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to
>   master master:7077 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown
>   in awaitResult:   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 01000B31     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:349)     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserializeStream(JavaSerializer.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:577)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:207)
>   ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]  at
>   org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:120)
>   ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]  at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
>   ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]  at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   ~[netty-all-4.0.43.Final.jar:4.0.43.Final]    ... 1 common frames
>   omitted

Any idea?

Comment: Try replacing `master` with the actual IP and see if it works?

Comment: what is container ip you have in etc/hosts?

Comment: Can you access a the admin UI from the container itself?

Comment: I tried replacing master with 192.168.99.100, the actual IP, which is `etc/hosts` too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are u running on Toolbox or Docker for Windows?

Comment: Toolbox in Windows 7.

Comment: @AdrianBer did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @perrohunter, I did NOT find a solution for this. For standalone you can do `.master("local")`, but whatever I tried it didn't work for a Spark cluster.